# Is it trivial to get $200$ algebraic abc triples of equal quality $1.6978...$ over isomorphic number fields?

Tags: nt.number-theory, number-fields, abc-conjecture

Got $200$ algebraic abc triples over distinct though isomorphic
number fields of equal quality $1.6978...$

Strongly suspect I can get as many as I like
(assuming the computations are correct).

> Is this result trivial?

Experiments with the best abc triples suggest that
when $a,b$ are mapped to isomorphic number field,
this decreases the quality significantly.

The definition of quality is from SOME EXAMPLES RELATED TO THE abc–CONJECTURE
FOR ALGEBRAIC NUMBER FIELDS, NIKLAS BROBERG

and it is

$$l_K(x)=\frac{\log{H_K(x,1-x,1)}}{\log{|\Delta_{K/Q}| + \log{N_K(x,1-x,1)}}} $$

Where $H_K$ is height function and $N_K$ is conductor.

My implementation agrees with Nitaj's tables and other papers.

Certainly bug in the implementation and/or sage is not excluded.

Comment: How does the 200 distribute over the isomorphic fields? Did you, say, get 4 examples that translated into 50 isomorphic fields? Anyway, the quality is directly related to the minimal polynomial of $x$, so I'm not surprised you can generate similar answers by isomorphic images of different conjugates.

Comment: @Aeryk Don't understand you question, would you please explain? If you can find 200+ examples of similar quality, this will be an answer to the question. My concern it is this will add at least 200 entries to [Nitaj's table](http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~nitaj/abc.html#Ten%20algebraic%20abc)

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is this: If $K_1= \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to $K_2 =\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ and $K_1$ contains an abc-triple, then of course $K_2$ contains the isomorphic image of the abc-triple, right?. But at the end of the day, this abc triple is going to embed into $\mathbb{C}$ in only a finite number of ways (and for Nitaj's examples that's only 2 or 3). So even though the triple can be written as elements of 200+ other $K_i$, there's really only a handful (through conjugations of complex embeddings) of triples. So how are the C-embeddings of your triples related?

Comment: @Aeryk Thanks, the question was stupid. My triples are trivial (identity accidentally caught the isomorphism).